# Can not Right click on Firefox, Firefox menu, dropbox menu doesn't show up

Tags: firefox

I had a problem with Firefox. When I start the firefox, it works. But for a while (randomly) I can't click on firefox menu anymore. The right click menu doesn't work either. The dropbox (select box) in website does not work.

I try use Firefox Nightly, remove old version Firefox and install new version... but i still got the same problem.

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04 32 bits.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use firefox in Archlinux and have met the same problem for a while too. There are some hints posted on ArchWiki:

[The menu cannot pop-up after updating to Firefox 13, It appears to happen especially to those who are using Fcitx 4.0.x (at that time Fcitx only supported XIM). With newer version of Fcitx, XIM is discouraged and you should set: GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox#The_menu_cannot_pop-up_after_updating_to_Firefox_13)

[For firefox above version 13, the popup menu may fail to work due to xim, please make sure that fcitx-gtk2 along with a latest version fcitx are installed.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fcitx)

I tried as it said but not worked for me. Not sure if it can help you.